# Apache server slow responses on AWS instance (Linux 2)

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-2.4, slow-connection

I have deployed a LAMP web app into two separate AWS instances (labeled prod and test). Both are t2.micro, but prod is the older Linux image and test is the new Linux 2 image. Using the chrome browser Dev Tool:

prod - total time: between 500ms and 600 ms
test - total time: between 15 seconds and 50 seconds

The TTFB on prod is less than 100 ms on all downloaded files (script, css, js, etc.)
The TTFB on test is 3 or more seconds...

Here is a link to the chrome dev tools screenshot:
[Chrome Dev Tool Timing Results](https://mafg-misc.s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/chrome-devtools-screen.png)

In addition, the download time for each file is a lot more on the test instance.

They have virtually the same apache conf, same memory usage (~50%), same code.

I have tried to figure out why and cannot find an answer. These are additional checks I have done:

**- Tried strace and it takes several seconds to take the next request (3.1s in the example below):**

6645  17:28:29 read(10, 0x55ff6e9b23f8, 8000) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable) <0.000007>
...
6645  17:28:32 <... poll resumed> )     = 1 ([{fd=10, revents=POLLIN}]) <3.108490>

**- Here strace also shows apache waits for a very long time for the socket (fd=10) to be available for writing again after a sendfile...**

6645  17:28:32 sendfile(10, 11, [76038] => [78918], 69895) = 2880 <0.000009>
6645  17:28:32 poll([{fd=10, events=POLLOUT}], 1, 60000 <unfinished ...>
....

6645  17:28:55 <... poll resumed> )     = 1 ([{fd=10, revents=POLLOUT}]) <23.333877>

**- I have tried to download a big file (3.6 MB) via scp and that is a lot faster (~1.7 MB/s). That tells me there is something wrong with apache or the sockets apache is using, perhaps?**

Any ideas what is happening on test? or if that is the expected speed from an t2.micro EC2 instance?

Thanks,

Mario.